# SQL Manipulating the join value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I think i asked the question without providing much clarity:

I have a temp table that stores results ext_results. I then have a CTE (myTrackingData) that retrieves predicted results. Both sets have a FK id that relates to the subjects.

I'd like to join the two which is easy enough but my problem is the myTrackingData only has predictions for "History", whereas ext_results has history stored as separate subjects (and hence separate ids).

When I join the two, what i'd like to do is manipulate the ext_results so that intsubjectID where the subject is like anyone of the history subjects only returns the id for the exact match History subject. Hence my ext_Results gets a match back to the predictions table.

I thought this statement would act as the join value using a select to get the ID's that match all those subjects like history but maybe my THEN statement is wrong so I'm getting 'subquery returned more than one value error' (maybe I need a WHERE clause in my WHEN statement?):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (SELECT SubjectName FROM subjects) LIKE '%History%'      
             THEN (SELECT SubjectsID FROM Subjects)
             ELSE intSubjectID
        END)
```

Any advice please.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I've amended the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my hunch was right. I just needed to add a where clause in my THEN Select statement:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (SELECT SubjectName FROM subjects) LIKE '%History%'      
         THEN (SELECT SubjectsID FROM Subjects **WHERE SubjectName='History'** )
         ELSE intSubjectID
    END)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would normally do something like this using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sh.SubjectsId, intSubjectID)
FROM . . . LEFT JOIN
     Subjects sh
     ON sh.? = ??.?? AND
        sh.SubjectName LIKE '%History%'
```

Your question doesn't provide information on how to link the tables, but this would seem to be the general direction.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the correct syntax for what are you trying to do

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN SubjectName LIKE '%History%' 
      THEN SubjectsID ELSE intSubjectID END AS RESULT FROM subjects
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right. what you are trying to do is:

for all the rows in table subjects:

1, If the subjectName contains 'History', then return its SubjectsID

2, If the subjectName does NOT contains 'History', return a value (intSubjectID ) instead. I will use 0 as the intSubjectId here.

Below is what I think works:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SubjectName LIKE '%History%' THEN SubjectsID ELSE 0 END
FROM Subjects
```